# sskeychain does not retain username and password

Tags: ios

I used `sskeychian` to store username and password with cocoapods. I added `sskeychain.h` and `sskeychain.m` and `sskeychainqudery.h` and `sskeychainquery.m` to my my project. And then I added `security.framework`. When I run ,it is OK. But,I want to retain username and password after closed application. How can I do that? Please help me.

**Here is my code**
   **In (void)viewDidLoad **

```
 [SSKeychain setPassword:self.password.text forService:@"AnyService" account:@"AnyUser"];
```

**In (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender**

```
 NSString *password = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"AnyService" account:@"AnyUser"];
```

Comment: R u trying in Simulator or real iphone device.? SSKeychain is only works in iphone devices.

Comment: I am working by Simulator.